# Getting error when adding new Peer to basicnetwork-Tuna App

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are using Tuna-App to setup basicnetwork along with tuna-app, and trying to add additional peer. Here is the source code of tuna-app
https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/fabric-material

We are able to add the Peer to the basicnetwork. We verified docker containers, all peer0, peer1, cli, ca, orderer, coughdb, coughdb2, and tuna-app-1.0 are running.

Peer0 sucessfully got added to channel with following command:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

We are trying to add Peer1 to the same channel with command:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

it throws an error:

> genesis block file not found open mychannel.block: no such file or directory

Please help me. How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the cli container:
`docker exec -it cli bash`

In that terminal, export the required variables:

`export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel`

`CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"`

`CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`

`CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051`

Add the peer to the channel:

`peer channel join -b mychannel.block`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands:

```
docker exec peer1.org1.example.com peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel
```

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@$org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example-swarm.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Answer (score -1):

Create channel from the CLI container. As in firstnetwork.

Because `mychannel.block` is available only in peer0.

You can't join the channel from peer1 since no `mychannel.block` file is available.